# SVN Diff of an Added file while specifying the file name

Tags: svn, diff

There are a few questions related to this on SO, as well as several bug reports sprinkled throughout google searches, but --new-file or -force or --notice-ancestry has not worked for me.

The file is NOT binary and I'd like something of the form to work:

```
svn diff -r XXXXXX TestHelloWorld.java
```

where TestHelloWorld.java is an added file.  Currently I get an "unable to find repo location..." and I've checked the revision numbers several times (I can get merge changes to show correctly)

Any ideas?

Comment: On second glance, I think this is indeed impossible.